# How to single out an object in a bytearray obtained from a pdf?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pdf

Let's say I have a pdf with 10 balloon callouts. Now I have converted that pdf into a bytearray using the following code.

```
file = open('cc.txt','rb')
for line in open("123.pdf", 'rb').readlines():
    file.write(line)
file.close()
```

Now, how can I identify the bytes that denote the balloon callouts?
I tried googling, but wasn't able to find any answers. Help me out guys.

Answer (score 2):

You can't because this is not how PDF files are structured internally (they are not line based). You need a PDF parsing library to get the objects corresponding to the balloon call-outs.

Comment: Can you provide me a way to approach this problem?

Comment: I don't know Python that well but there is the pdfrw library that should allow you to do that.